# How to perform a field describe dynamically using the API name of an sObject?

Tags: apex, map, describesobject

I am trying to get describe information about an sObject similar to this:

```
public Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap{get;set;} 
fieldMap=Schema.sObjectType.Lead.fields.getMap();
```

However, I want to substitute my own String variable "Field" instead of "LEAD" which is Standard object name.

```
myString='Schema.sObjectType.' + Field+ '.fields.getMap();';       
fieldMap = myString;
```

Error Message : : Illegal assignment from String to MAP`<String,Schema.SObjectField>`

So Is there any Conversion Method for String to Map ? Or Any Suggestions where I can easily assign myString in fieldMap  ?

Comment: I am trying to get List of all the fields in selected Object, where I have got API name of selected object in the "Field" variable. so by putting that in Map I am adding its fields in table below this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
  Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
                    Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(Field);
                    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = sobjType.getDescribe();
                    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> M = r.fields.getMap();
                    fieldMap=M;
```